# UIScrollView root view shown under a translucent navigation bar

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistoryboardsegue

In a storyboard there's a view controller that has translucent navigation bar, the root view is a `UIScrollView`.

Everything works great at start, `UIScrollView` has the right `contentInsets` (set automatically), content is shown behind the translucent navigation bar.

Suddenly, after pushing **any** view controller, either with `performSegueWithIdentifier:` or using IB's relationships, the root view of the target VC is being shown below the navigation bar, even though it's marked to be shown under top bars and was set to automatically adjust content insets.

To make sure it's not a problem with the pushed view controller, I've pushed the same view controller, the one that worked fine - but after being pushed the navigation bar became opaque.

It happens on iOS 7 and 8, on any screen size. It doesn't happen at other navigation controllers in my app.

Any idea why the root view is shown under navigation bar, after being pushed?

**Update**

When changing the root view of the pushed view controller to `UIView` instead of `UIScrollView`, it works fine.

So when pushing a view controller with a `UIScrollView` as root view, this happens. Some debug info running on a 3.5" screen (_pagesScrollView is a UIScrollView reference to the root view) -

```
_pagesScrollView.contentInset = {0, 0, 0, 0}
_pagesScrollView.frame = {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}
self.view.frame = {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}
```

You can see that contentInset wasn't set this time and that height is 480, but it looks like origin of (0, 0) is **below** the navigation bar.

It looks like the problem occurs when pushing a VC with a `UIScrollView` root view after another VC with a `UIScrollView`.

**Update 2**

Fixed question - why is view.frame.origin of (0, 0) is shown under the navigation bar, when view controller has "under top bars" and "adjust content insets" enabled?

Comment: Can you post the project (or a reduced version of it) on github? I can't reproduce the issue in my own code.

Comment: I'll try to create a mini project that reproduces this.

Comment: It doesn't reproduce on a separate project. Tried to isolate things but couldn't find what's causing this.

Comment: :) Excellent. That is what I was trying to get you to see. Moreover, you have already deduced the thing that was going to be my next suggestion: the navigation bar is not losing its transparency at all! The reason you see nothing behind it is merely that _there is nothing behind it_. So now you can delete / edit this question (and your test project) to focus on why _that_ is happening.

Comment: Good point, so the problem is actually that the `UIScrollView` is shown **under** the navigation bar - even though it shows frame.origin of (0, 0). Maybe I should keep this question open, in case someone else searches for the same symptoms?

Comment: We haven't solved it yet, have we? I'm still hoping for your example that reproduces the problem.